# How can I stop whatsapp message to get deliver to my device?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, whatsapp-messenger

I want my whatsapp to not fetch any message even when my internet connection is on. I want to use my device with internet and also want other's people whatsapp message that are sent to me to not to get deliver to my device.

Comment: Just don't open the app? Force close it so it no longer appears in Running services, then use some other apps like Greenify to keep it so.

Answer (score 0):

**Your question is unclear, please try reframing it.**

If you want that WhatsApp should not work, then you should uninstall it.

If you want to still keep it and see that it does not use data on background, you better turn off background data for the app in settings.

If you want to only send message and not receive,  that is not possible.